# Angular 2 INTERNATIONALIZATION (I18N):Not able find target tag in ganerated xlf file

Tags: angularjs, typescript, internationalization

i am using angular-cli, followed [angular-io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html#!#app-pre-translation) to generate in Spanish language.

app.component.html

```
<h2 i18n="header">Login form</h2>
<div>
  <span i18n>Email</span>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Your email" i18n-placeholder>
</div>
<div>
  <span i18n>Password</span>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" i18n-placeholder>
</div>

<hr>

<div i18n>If you want to search something, go to <a href="http://google.com">Google</a></div>
```

message.es.xlf

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">   
<file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="ng2.template">
        <body>
        </body>   
</file>
 </xliff>
```

getting generated `message.es.xlf` file once completing `./node_modules/.bin/ng-xi18n`,but not able to find target tag in that file.
please help me

Answer (score 0):

A little late but may help someone. Had the same problem, I resolved it by specifying the output file:

```
./node_modules/.bin/ng-xi18n  --i18nFormat=xmb  --outFile=messages.xmb
```

Answer (score 0):

It is 2019, when I come back to Angular, and I found this same issue. The problem is that your XLF file must have a pair of target tags for every pair of source tags. You may add those tags manually, probably by copying and pasting and renaming the source tags, or you may use this script:

https://github.com/geocarlos/angular-i18n-target-tagger